# loop with condition does not end vs loop with if statement

Tags: python, loops

I am creating a game using a nested `for` loop here, however for some reason, I can't find it yet, it keeps looping indefinitely even if there is a `break` statement on the nested `for` loop. I don't know how the `for` loop keeps on going despite an `if` statement at its beginning once the nested `while` loop meets its `life > 1` condition.

```py
import random


life = 3
right = 0
wrong = 0
word = ""
nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

random.shuffle(nums)
nums.pop()

while life > 0 :
    
    for n in nums :     
        if life < 1 :
           
            print("Sorry, Number of trials Exceeded")
            print("---------------------------")
            print("END OF GAME")
            print("\n")
            print("CORRECT SPELLING SCORE: " + str(right))
            print("\n")
            print("WRONG SPELLING SCORE: " + str(wrong))
            break
            
        
        if n == 0:
            word = "zero"
        elif n == 1:
            word = "one"
        elif n == 2:
            word = "two"    
        elif n == 3:
            word = "three"  
        elif n == 4:
            word = "four"
        elif n == 5:
            word = "five"    
        elif n == 6:
            word = "six"    
        elif n == 7:
            word = "seven"
        elif n == 8:
            word = "eight"    
        elif n == 9:
            word = "nine"    
        elif n == 10:
            word = "ten"
        
        print("spell " + str(n) + ": ")
        ans = str(input())
        
        while ans.lower() != word and life > 1 :
            life -=1
            wrong += 1
            print("Incorrect spelling. " + str(life) + " trials left")
            print("spell " + str(n) + ": ")
            ans = str(input())
        
 

if life > 0:
    print("---------------------------")
    print("END OF GAME")
    print("\n")
    print("CORRECT SPELLING SCORE: " + str(right))
    print("\n")
    print("WRONG SPELLING SCORE: " + str(wrong))
```

However, it works well as expected if I remove the `AND` on the `while` loop and put an `if` statement inside to check for `life`.

```py
import random


life = 3
right = 0
wrong = 0
word = ""
nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

random.shuffle(nums)
nums.pop()

while life > 0 :
    
    for n in nums :     
        if life < 1 :
            print("Sorry, Number of trials Exceeded")
            print("---------------------------")
            print("END OF GAME")
            print("\n")
            print("CORRECT SPELLING SCORE: " + str(right))
            print("\n")
            print("WRONG SPELLING SCORE: " + str(wrong))
            break
        
        if n == 0:
            word = "zero"
        elif n == 1:
            word = "one"
        elif n == 2:
            word = "two"    
        elif n == 3:
            word = "three"  
        elif n == 4:
            word = "four"
        elif n == 5:
            word = "five"    
        elif n == 6:
            word = "six"    
        elif n == 7:
            word = "seven"
        elif n == 8:
            word = "eight"    
        elif n == 9:
            word = "nine"    
        elif n == 10:
            word = "ten"
        
        print("spell " + str(n) + ": ")
        ans = str(input())
        
        while ans.lower() != word :
            life -=1
            wrong += 1
            print("Incorrect spelling. " + str(life) + " trials left")
            print("spell " + str(n) + ": ")
            ans = str(input())
            
            if life <1:
                print("Sorry, Number of trials Exceeded")
                print("---------------------------")
                print("END OF GAME")
                print("\n")
                print("CORRECT SPELLING SCORE: " + str(right))
                print("\n")
                print("WRONG SPELLING SCORE: " + str(wrong))
                break
        
 

if life > 0:
    print("---------------------------")
    print("END OF GAME")
    print("\n")
    print("CORRECT SPELLING SCORE: " + str(right))
    print("\n")
    print("WRONG SPELLING SCORE: " + str(wrong))
```

Comment: You have a ton of elif's, you dont need that. Use a dictionary.

Comment: Or a list, since they're sequential numbers.

Comment: The condition `life > 1` fails when `life == 1`. But your check at the top is for `life < 1`. It never becomes less than 1 because it stops decrementing when it's equal to 1.

Comment: I avoid nesting loops, instead I create separate function for each loop. This way you can call return instead of break and it is clear where the execution continues.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar answered your question.  As was pointed out by others, Python gives you ways to streamline your code for solutions like this one (hopefully) without sacrificing clarity.

Example:

```
import random

MAX_LIVES = 3

right_answers = 0
lives_remaining = MAX_LIVES

numtuples = [
    ("0", "zero"), ("1", "one"), ("2", "two"), ("3", "three"), ("4", "four"), ("5", "five"),
    ("6", "six"), ("7", "seven"), ("8", "eight"), ("9", "nine"), ("10", "ten")
]

for numstr, numspell in random.sample(numtuples, len(numtuples)):    

    while lives_remaining:
        answer = input(f"Spell {numstr}: ")
        if answer == numspell: 
            right_answers += 1
            break;
        else:
            lives_remaining -= 1

    if not lives_remaining:
        print("\nSorry, no more lives left.")
        break
            
print("---------------------------")
print("END OF GAME")
print("RIGHT ANSWERS: " + str(right_answers))
print("WRONG ANSWERS: " + str(MAX_LIVES - lives_remaining))
```